# Data Frame in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to download Apple's stock price in Python. I noticed that the data however wasn't in a data frame. It was jumbled when I viewed it in my Spyder IDE. How do I turn coerce it into a data frame/matrix format and how do I reference data columns such as "Volume" "Adjusted Close"? I would appreciate your help.

```
import ystockquote as ys
aapl=ys.get_historical_prices("aapl","2010-01-01","2015-01-01")
```

Comment: You need to give more information I think. What format is the data in, and what format do you want it in. Are you talking about a pandas data frame?

Comment: yes. Pandas data frame. I apologize, I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the format of the data you have is, but you can create data frames with something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Volume': aapl['Volume'],
                        'Adjusted Close': aapl['Adjusted Close']})
```

The keys of the dictionary will be the column names of the data frame, and the corresponding entries will become the columns.

Have a look at the [DataFrame documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), it might give you some clues.

Comment: Thanks so much! I noticed when I ran the code df = pd.DataFrame(aapl) the variable df did not show up in the variable explorer on the Spyder IDE. Is that normal?

Comment: I would like to convert the entire dataset into a dataframe and then reference a variable of interest such as "Volume" using a command such as df[["Volume"]] or df$Volume.

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide information on what the aapl variable is?